# custom number formatter with currency symbol

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsnumberformatter

I have a text field where the user should be enter a price.
On this text field I dragged a Custom Number Formatter with this settings:

[image]

This works nearly perfect but I have a problem with the "Format".
At the moment it is: `.#.##`

But what I have to change to show automatically the correct user currency symbol at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the static solution you can simply change format from `.#.##` to `.#.## €`

If you're looking for universal way to do it, you're interested with symbol `¤`, which is responsible for currency sign.

So the format which are you looking for is `,#.## ¤`

Last step is to check option `lenient`, otherwise you need to provide full format in text field.

**More details**

Since OSX 10.9 and iOS 7 the format strings uses patterns from [the Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35) of [version 31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31).

You can find all number format patterns in this version [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-numbers.html#Number_Format_Patterns)

[Apple documentation about number formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1)

Comment: yes this is the static solution. but what is if the user have $ instead € ?

Comment: So what are you looking for is universal mechanism in storyboard for printing symbol at the end?

Comment: yes if this is possible. I hopped there is an placeholder like `.#.##. [Currency Symbol]`

Comment: i tried your format: But the sample output shows 155,00 (like before) instead of 155,00 € or 155,00 $

Comment: Try with comma instead of dot `,#.## ¤ `

Comment: okay, but next little problem. the user have to write now completely: 155,00 € - I thought that the user can write 155 and it will be automatically 155,00 € - like demo in the storyboard :(

Comment: You need to check option `lenient` in storyboard :)

Comment: yeah i saw this option a few seconds ago :)  - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the number formatter also like this:

```
let price = 592.12
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency

//change this to get your desired currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;

let priceText = formatter.string(for: price)
//priceText = 592,12 €
```

Comment: yes, the programmatically way is solution which i knew. but is there also a way to solve it with the storyboard settings?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the default currency mode provided by the formatter or do you need to do additional custom formatting:

[image]